# Drawing a table faster and more efficient

Tags: html, html-table, logic, processing-efficiency

I was wondering if you coukd help me to make things faster in my html script. Im trying to draw a table and add color to each td but its veryyyy slow

Sorry about this but im just going to copy the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Random color</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body{margin:0;}

    table, td, tr{
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table{
        margin: 0;
    }

    html, body, div, table{
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tableCont"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var  pixels=400//window.screen.availWidth*window.devicePixelRatio;
    var html="<table>";
var rand1, rand2, rand3;

    for(var i=0; i<pixels; i++){
        html+="<tr>";
        for(var j=0; j<pixels; j++){
   rand1=Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
          rand2=Math.floor(Math.random()*256);
        rand3=Math.floor(Math.random()*256);

            html+='<td id="t' + (j+(i*pixels)) + '" style ="width: '+ Math.floor(window.screen.availWidth*window.devicePixelRatio/pixels) +'px; height: '+ Math.floor(100/pixels)+'%; background-color: rgb('+rand1+','+rand2+','+rand3+')"></td>'
        }
        html+="</tr>";
    }   
    html+="</table>";

 document.getElementById("tableCont").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you tried profiling your code to see where it spends most of its time?
 https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/

Comment: Thanks José Luís will see whrn i get home

Comment: Looks like you are creating 400 rows with 400 td's each. So that's 160,000 new elements to be added, from a html string. I bet you it slow Is this really what you want to do?
Also: you are doing the same calculation again and again in the loop...

What is the problem you  are trying to solve? Looks like a matrix of colored pixels? Have a look at <canvas>

Comment: @JelmerJellema Yeah i'm just putting random colors on the screen just as a little experiment. However it seem like canvas can help performance, maybe if i am able to draw dots with it. It works thanks!